# asking to use GET in a servlet where i have only used POST method

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

**This is my html code**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>New Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <form method="post" action="display">
```

**I have used POST method above for servlet action**

```
            Enter Name: <input type="text" name="name">
            Enter City <input type="text" name="city">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>        
    </body>
</html>
```

**Servlet1.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException
```

used "**doPost**" for the POST method defined in the html form

```
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        Cookie c1 = new Cookie("name",request.getParameter("name"));
        Cookie c2 = new Cookie("city",request.getParameter("city"));

        response.addCookie(c1);
        response.addCookie(c2);
```

**redirecting to 2nd servlet through this form**

```
        response.sendRedirect("servlet2");

    }
}
```

**servlet2.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class servlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
    response) throws ServletException, IOException
```

I am getting an error saying "**HTTP GET Method is not supported by this url**", however I have nowhere mentioned GET in my code.

```
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        Cookie c[] = request.getCookies();
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        for(Cookie cookie : c)
        {
            if(cookie.getName().equals("name") || 
cookie.getName().equals("city"))
            {
                pw.println(cookie.getValue()+"<br>");
            }
        }
        pw.println("Print using cookie");
    }
}
```

the servlet works perfectly fine if I use "**doGET**" method in servlet2.java. However I am using **POST** method then **why does it require "doGET"??**

I get the below error for the above code.
    HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

```
type: Status report

message: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

description: The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested 
resource.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
```

Comment: response.sendRedirect("servlet2") causes the browser to send a GET request to Servlet2. Since Servlet2 does not support GET method, you are getting the error that GET method is not supported.

If you want the above flow, then you will have to implement doGet in Servlet2 to handle the request.

Comment: thank you, got the point. Just out of curiosity, is there a way where i can use POST for 2nd servlet?

Comment: Use [`RequestDispatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)